# FIFO class in python library?

Tags: python, fifo

Below is a simple implementation of a FIFO in Python. My question is whether anything equivalent already exists in a maintained package, especially anything in the standard library, as it seems like a reasonably common thing to want to do.

Functionality: you must be able to `append` to and iterate over it like a list, but when iteration yields an element, the internal reference to that element must be destroyed.

Here is example of what I want to do with it:

```
f = Fifo()

# append to it

for i in range(5):
    f.append(i)
print("length:", len(f))

# iterate over it, including appending while iterating

for i in f:
    print("item:", i)
    if i == 3:
        f.append("something")
print("all for now")

# iterate again (maybe we didn't previously iterate fully,
# or, as in this example, appended some more items afterwards)

f.append("another thing")
f.append("and another thing")
print("length:", len(f))
for i in f:
    print("item:", i)
```

to give:

```
length: 5
item: 0
item: 1
item: 2
item: 3
item: 4
item: something
all for now
length: 2
item: another thing
item: and another thing
```

And here is my implementation. (This uses a dictionary. A marginally simpler but less efficient alternative uses a list internally.)

```
class Fifo:

    def __init__(self):
        self._d = {}
        self._cur = 0  # next key to pop

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self._d)

    def append(self, v):
        self._d[self._cur + len(self._d)] = v

    def __next__(self):
        if self._d:
            v = self._d.pop(self._cur)
            self._cur += 1
            return v
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    def __iter__(self):
        return self
```

Comment: Have you seen [queue.Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html?highlight=queue#module-queue)  ?

Comment: @BalajiAmbresh Thanks - I had a look but it doesn't seem to support an iteration interface - see my comment under Minn's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```py
from queue import SimpleQueue


class Fifo(SimpleQueue):
    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __len__(self):
        return self.qsize()

    def __next__(self):
        if not self.empty():
            return self.get()
        raise StopIteration

fifo = Fifo()
fifo.put(10)
fifo.put(20)
for item in fifo:
    print(item)

print(f'fifo size after iteration {len(fifo)}')
```

Output

```
10
20
fifo size after iteration 0
```

Comment: Thanks, voted up. This certainly works and has the correct interface. It still involves your own class on top of what the library provides (although fewer lines of code than I needed to use on top of a dictionary), so it would be nice if there is anything that works out of the box.

Comment: @alaniwi If you're looking for a queue with iterator support that pops during iteration, no such thing exists out of the box in python.

Comment: Thanks - if the answer is no, then that is still an answer, even if not the one I was hoping for. I wonder if it would be worth one of us submitting a feature request for `Queue` to suggest adding the methods from your subclass in order to support this?

Comment: @alaniwi Go for it. Out of curiosity, why would you need this behavior?

Comment: I don't yet have a specific use case, but it is quite easy to imagine that you may want to iterate over a queue of tasks, and when you are doing one task it results in needing to add some other task to the queue for later. Obviously you could loop using a `while not queue.empty():` test but using an iterator feels kind of clean and pythonic.

Comment: So for example, suppose your task involves processing object `obj` at processing stage `n`, and you have a bunch of objects that should all be processed at stage `n` before any of them are processed at stage `n+1` - then your code to process an object at stage `n` could include adding the `n+1` task to the back of the queue. Then you just start by pushing all the stage `0` tasks to the queue and start iterating.

Comment: @alaniwi My point is, you can do everything you need without the need for an explicit iterator. If you can convince the moderators with your PEP, have fun.

Comment: I added https://bugs.python.org/issue41339 - it says that very simple feature requests (which I think this qualifies as) can be added via the bug tracker. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/queue.html#queue.Queue)

```py
queue = Queue()

queue.put(0)
queue.put(1)

while not queue.empty():
  print(queue.get())
```

Comment: That certainly works, so I've voted it up, but before marking it as accepted I will wait to see if there are any other solutions which permit normal iteration in the caller.

Answer (score 4):

As FIFO data structure you could use next:

- `list` - `append()` and `pop()` function is used.
- `collections.deque` - `append()` and `popleft()`
- `Queue.queue` - `get()` and `put()` and etc. It is suitable for multi-threaded programming

Comment: Thanks - voted up for the helpful suggestions, but none of these support an iteration-type interface (iterating over a `list` will not remove the item; `collections.deque` is iterable but breaks if you append while iterating; `Queue.queue` is not iterable).